# If $N(t)$ is a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda(t)$ then is $N'(t)=N(t+2)-N(2)$ a poisson process?

Tags: stochastic-processes

If $N(t)$ is a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda(t)$ then is $N'(t)=N(t+2)-N(2)$ a poisson process? 
I think it should be poisson process as it is like observing a poisson process after time $2$ but how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** A Process $N$ is a poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ iff:

1. $N(0) = 0$ almost surely.
2. $N(t) - N(s) \sim \mathrm{Poi}(\lambda(t-s))$ for all $0 \le s < t$.
3. $N(t) - N(s)$ is independent of $\sigma(\{N(k) \mid 0 \le k \le s\})$ for all $0 \le s < t$.
4. $N$ has almost surely càdlàg paths.

Comment: For OP's benefit, condition 4 should be equivalent to $P(N(t+h)-N(t)>1)=o(h)$.

Comment: @AlexR. I don't see why this makes the proof easier, it's pretty obvious from the definition that $N'$ holds the last property if $N$ holds it.

Comment: What is càdlàg paths?

Comment: càdlàg means right continuous with left limits.